# Magento 2: How to Apply Coupon Code based on Product Customizable Option

Tags: magento2, custom-options, coupon, coupon-codes, promotions

I want to create coupon code for specific product and custom option

> E.g.
>
> **Sku:** Test1
>
> **Custom Option:**
>
> Name: Demo Custom Option
>
> Option Type: Field

I want to apply the coupon code if customer have enter the name, if not filled customer will not allow to apply the coupon.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You can create coupon code via backend.

> Steps : Login to backend -> Menu -> Marketing -> Cart Price Rule ->
>   Add New Rule

Under that Form you will find conditions section, Under That section you can add conditions based on your criteria.

You will see Attribute Drop-down Under Condition section.

If your Attribute not there then, you need to follow step,

> Backend Login -> Menu -> Stores -> Products (Attribute section) ->
>   search your attribute - > Click on that Row

Under that page you will find storefront properties, in that change the value of **Use for Promo Rule Conditions** to **YES** .

Run php bin/magento c:f command via Terminal.

Comment: You are missing the point. OP asked if it was possible to have a condition based on the customizable options of a product, not a product attribute.